# How do I add a conditional comma to data using Angular?

Tags: angularjs

Using Angular, I would like to know how to add a space before, and a comma after {{name}} so that if there is not a name entered into the input, then the web page will just display: ***Hello*** ... BUT, if there is a name entered, the page will display: ***Hello Sarah,***

How do I make that extra space and extra comma appear conditional to whether or not the name exists?

```
<h1>Hello {{name}},</h1>
<h1>Welcome to my website!</h1>
<h1>Please enter your name:</h1>
<input type="text" ng-model="name">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ng-show`:

```
<h1>Hello<span ng-show="name"> {{name}},</span></h1>
```

This will display the span if `name` is truthy.  Since the span contains the extra space, the name itself, and the comma, only "Hello" will be displayed if `name` isn't set.

Comment: Perfect!! Do you know how would I get the input to disappear once a name is entered?

Comment: You can use `ng-show` on any HTML element, including the input.  If you want the input to disappear after you enter a name, use this:

`<input type="text" ng-show="!name" ng-model="name" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">`

Note how I've set the model to update on blur... else it would disappear as soon as you type something.

Comment: Also, I discovered you can use { updateOn: 'change blur' } to enable the enter key to trigger the hide as well. Thanks Mike!